# Hibernate transaction management

Tags: java, hibernate, session, transactions, multiple-instances

Well, I've been working with hibernate since a little time ago, so i'm still learning stuff.
My problem is that I don't want to open and close Transaction within a method, i mean, the class that manage that transaction, i want it to work as an invoice system, for example, you open the invoice and start adding invoice details, but don't commit any of that work untill I add the last invoice detail.

i've show what i have:

Handler Class:

```
public class ModuloVenta {

    public Integer vender(Venta venta) {
        Integer idVenta = null;
        Transaction tx = null;
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            idVenta = (Integer) session.save(venta);
            tx.commit();
        } catch(HibernateException ex) {
            if(tx!=null) tx.rollback();
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return idVenta;
    }

    public Integer agregarDetalle(DetalleVenta detalle) {
        Integer idDetalle = null;
        Transaction tx = null;
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            idDetalle = (Integer) session.save(detalle);
            tx.commit();
        } catch(HibernateException ex) {
            if(tx!=null) tx.rollback();
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }       
        return idDetalle;
    }   
}
```

The methods "vender" and "agregarDetalle" works separately, but i want them to first open with method "vender" and then be able to use "agregarDetalle" and use it as many times i want untill I call a method, for example, "finish" to end the transaction.
How can i do that?

Thanks!

Comment: How about having starting the transaction in vender method and keeping the session as a instance level variable? The transaction can be committed and the session can be closed in a new method (for e.g. finish) which gets called after everything is done?

Comment: going to try it.. thanks! But one question, is safe to have a session object like an instance attribute?

Comment: No. Hibernate session is not thread safe so it won't be advisable to keep it as a instance variable if the application is going to be accessed concurrently. I think the simplest way to implement your requirement would be to use spring transactions - http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html

Comment: Thanks! is there another way of doing the same thing without spring transactions?